# Updating State Through props with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to update the state of something on a click from a component by lifting up the state and passing it as a prop into the other component and trying to update it.

this is the App.js

```
function App() {
  const [currentConfig, setCurrentConfig] = useState(0);
  const availableConfigs = [
    { id: 1, name: "Config 1", number: 1, key: 1 },
    { id: 2, name: "Config 2", number: 2, key: 2 },
    { id: 3, name: "Config 3", key: 3 },
    { id: 4, name: "Config 4", key: 4 },
    { id: 5, name: "Config 5", key: 5 },
    { id: 6, name: "Config 6", key: 6 },
    { id: 7, name: "Config 7", key: 7 },
  ];

  const [configs, setConfigs] = useState(availableConfigs);

  //function undoConfigAnimation(currentConfig) {}

  return (
    <div>
      <Tree
        configs={configs}
        animateConfigs={startConfigAnimation}
        setConfig={setCurrentConfig}
        currentConfig={currentConfig}
      />
      <NavBar />
    </div>
  );

  function startConfigAnimation(configClicked) {
    console.log(currentConfig);
    configs.forEach((config) => {
      if (configClicked !== config.name) {
        var elm = document.getElementById(config.name);
        elm.style.transform = "translate(-200px)";
        setTimeout(() => (elm.style.transform = "rotateZ(180deg)"), 1000);
      }
    });
  }
}

export default App;
```

this is the component

```
function Tree(props) {
  return (
    <div class="treeContainer">
      {props.configs.map((config) => {
        return (
          <div
            id={config.name}
            class="container1"
            onClick={() => {
              props.setConfig(config.name);

              props.animateConfigs(config.name);
              if (props.currentConfig !== config.name) {
                props.setConfig.bind(config.name);
              }
            }}
          >
            <Configs configNumber={config.number} configName={config.name} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
export default Tree;
```

currently, it does update the state, but it only updates it to the state before the click so an example output if the currentConfig === 0 would be as follows

click config 1
currentConfig = 0
click config 2
currentConfig = "config 1"

Answer (score 1):

Since the setState is async, the console.log will always be one behind. This does not mean that the state is not updated, but only not displayed in the console or yet available in the function.

So the flow would be:

1. You dispatch the change.
2. You call `startConfigAnimation`, but it is still in sync, so that `currentConfig` is still the previous value.
3. The state is updated with the new value.

There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. Use a useEffect:
   Listen to the `currentConfig` with a useEffect and trigger the animation, if the config changes.

```
React.useEffect(() => startConfigAnimation(currentConfig), [currentConfig])
```

2. You are already passing the new/updated config to `startConfigAnimation` so you could be using that.

Comment: Where would I actually call the useEffect()? and I thought the same thing with the passing it in, but I need it to be global as well so I can pass that into another component that will handle some different animation functions.